# nginx! how to release old array memory if push an element into array and the old array is full?

Tags: c, nginx

Please see the following source code!

```
void *ngx_array_push(ngx_array_t *a)
{
    void        *elt, *new;
    size_t       size;
    ngx_pool_t  *p;

   if (a->nelts == a->nalloc) {

        /* the array is full */

        size = a->size * a->nalloc;

        p = a->pool;

        if ((u_char *) a->elts + size == p->d.last
            && p->d.last + a->size <= p->d.end)
        {
            /*
             * the array allocation is the last in the pool
             * and there is space for new allocation
             */

            p->d.last += a->size;
            a->nalloc++;

        } else {
            /* allocate a new array */

            new = ngx_palloc(p, 2 * size);
            if (new == NULL) {
                return NULL;
            }

            ngx_memcpy(new, a->elts, size);
            a->elts = new;        //This place
            a->nalloc *= 2;
        }
    }

    elt = (u_char *) a->elts + a->size * a->nelts;
    a->nelts++;

    return elt;
}
```

variable "new" is a new memory! a->elts point the old memory. According to “a->elts = new;”，a->elts point the new memory. However, the old memory do not release. If do not consider the old memory release?

Comment: Should'nt you be calling something like ngx_free( a->elts ); after the memcpy?